# Python solution needed

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, list

I have three lists Teams= [T1,T2,T3,T4]   and there number of wins Nwins[10,12,10,5] and the goals they scored 
GScored[33,34,22,28]. i want to find the season winner based on their number of wins however if two teams have same wins in the season then the number of goals they have scored. similarly the one with least wins will be relegated and if there are two then the one with least goals scored will get eliminated. Your help will be appreciated

Comment: Do you have any example code to offer? SO isn't a code-writing service, please attempt something before asking SO to do it for you without any clear efforts.

Comment: It is unclear what e.g. Nwins[10,12,10,5] means. Do you mean that `Nwins` is a list, like `Nwins = [10, 12, 10, 5]`?

Comment: You must edit your question otherwise it will likely be flagged and removed. please include code snippets and examples.

Comment: yes. these are three lists, the first contain team names, the second contain the overall wins in a season and the third contain their scores. I can use the max function and the min function to find the leader and relegating team but i am stucked when two teams have same wins

Answer (score 2):

```
winner = max(zip(Nwins, GScored, Teams))[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Teams = ["T1","T2","T3","T4"]
NoWins = [10,0,10,5]
GScored = [33,34,22,28]

highestWins = max(NoWins)
if NoWins.count(highestWins) == 1:
   winner = Teams[NoWins.index(highestWins)] 
else:
   options = [g for i, g in enumerate(GScored) if NoWins[i] == highestWins]
   winner = [t for i, t in enumerate(Teams) if NoWins[i] == highestWins][options.index(max(options))]

lowestWins = min(NoWins)
if NoWins.count(lowestWins) == 1:
   relegated = Teams[NoWins.index(lowestWins)]
else:
   options = [g for i, g in enumerate(GScored) if NoWins[i] == lowestWins]
   relegated = [t for i, t in enumerate(Teams) if NoWins[i] == lowestWins][options.index(min(options))]
```

Which gives `winner` as `"T1"` (I modified your example) and `relegated` as `"T2"`.

And if `NoWins = [0, 2, 2, 2]` and `GScored = [4, 4, 3, 3]`, `winner` is `"T2"` and `relegated` is `"T1"`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Good point, I didn't restrict the goals scored comparison to just the top teams, I will add to the answer now!

Comment: @StefanPochmann I have finally got it to work, **extremely** messily, but it works. Successfully passed all the tests  (regulation drawing scores as well as winner drawing scores) so at least it works! Nevertheless, your answer is *much, much, much* neater and simpler so +1 from me **:)**

Comment: @StefanPochman Will look in sec, https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/e.g.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I have finally made it work I think, please try and find a case where it fails but it seems to pass everything now! Thanks for your patience. **:)**

Comment: Yeah, I think now the only thing wrong with it is the indentation by 3 spaces :-P